# Using ifelse with conditional statements based on vector indices to loop down rows

Tags: r

Essentially I have a data frame. From this I've taken 2 new indices to indicate to me a value for each row that will be used in changing this dataset. I also have a code to replace the values as I'd like them replaced (essentially up to the column indicated by the new index is changed to a 0). I'm just not sure how to put this all together.

This is the data frame I was originally working with, the ind1 and ind2 were used to create a new indices that I have as separate vectors.

```
COL1 <- c(1,1,1,NA,1,1)
COL2 <- c(1,NA,NA,1,1,1)
COL3 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
ind1 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
ind2 <- c(3,3,2,3,3,3)
Data <- data.frame (COL1, COL2, COL3, ind1, ind2)
Data
COL1 COL2 COL3 ind1 ind2
1    1    1    1    3    
1    NA   1    2    3
1    NA   1    1    2   
NA   1    1    2    3
1    1    1    1    3
1    1    1    2    3
```

the new vector indices looks like this and are currently not in the data frame

```
actual <- c(5,3,4,1,1,2)
prediction <- c(1,1,2,5,5,1)
```

Essentially what I would like to happen is for the function to evaluate actual > prediction for each row and if this is **true** then it runs the function below **on that row**

```
replace(Data, cbind(rep(1:NROW(Data), Data$ind1), sequence(Data$ind1)), 0)
```

and if actual > prediction is **false** then it runs the function below **on that row**

```
replace(Data, cbind(rep(1:NROW(Data), Data$ind2), sequence(Data$ind2)), 0)
```

for this data frame example i would expect the output to be a new data frame where

```
Data2
COL1 COL2 COl3 ind1 ind2
1    1    1    1    3
1    1    1    2    3
1    1    1    1    2
0    0    0    2    3
0    0    0    1    3
0    0    1    2    3
```

What I've tried so far is...

```
Data2<- c()
for (i in 1:NROW (Data)) {if (actual < prediction) {
  Data2[i]<- replace(Data, cbind(rep(1:NROW(Data), Data$ind1), sequence(Data$ind1)), 0)
 } else {
  Data2[i]<- replace(Data, cbind(rep(1:NROW(Data), Data$ind2), sequence(Data$ind2)), 0)
 }  
}
```

This gives me a list of lists output for Data2. But what I am looking for is a new dataframe.

Comment: @thelatemail fixed, sorry I wrote this in a hurry but actual vectors are ones i have from using an apply function on this data frame, for this example I just through some random ones up there

Comment: I still don't really follow this. For each row where actual > prediction, you change data within the whole dataset?

Comment: for each row where actual > prediction then the first function is executed on that row. When the evaluation is NOT actual > prediction then the second function is executed on that row. I want this process to iterate through all rows.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you have tried?

Comment: @JamieVarney - to me that function doesn't make sense to run on a single row though. You are indexing multiple rows and columns in a single row as part of the `replace`ment.

Comment: @thelatemail yes perhaps in this case it is better to use something like```as.data.frame (t( apply(Data, 1, function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) <= x[4], 0)))[,-4])```**if the evaluation was true and we are indexing from the ind1 column**

Comment: Are you replacing the row based on the condition?

Comment: @MichaelVine the idea is the evaluation is based on the external vectors actual > prediction (which have the same number of rows as the data frame) then if the first row for those vectors is true the first row in the data frame is changed based on function 1. if the first row for those vectors is false then the first row in the data frame is changed based on function 2. this iterates until reaching``` NROW(Data)```

Comment: The issue you are running into is you are changing the Data variable in the first iteration of the loop. You should create a NULL variable and fill it based on the vectors... that or I don't understand the explanation.

Comment: @MichaelVine coming back to this problem, I've appended the code to create a new empty data frame where I want to store the new rows, however I am now getting a list of lists output into the Data2 I created instead of it just being filled row by row with the new information

Comment: @JamieVarney, i want to assist you more, but I am having trouble understanding the issues. your loop creates 6 dataframes, I can mimic your code, but I cannot get your desired outcome. I don't want to answer the question because it is not correct. [here](https://codeshare.io/GLDNr7) is a link to the code I wrote which is similar to your output.

Comment: @MichaelVine thank you for the code help, I've tried implementing your code in my data frame but what I'm finding now is that it is not taking the ```if``` arguement even if the ```if```` logic is met. I've attached the link to my alterations [here](https://codeshare.io/GLDNr7). and I am having the same issue where ```if```` statement is not being executed even when logic is met

Answer (score 0):

After our many back a forth, I believe this is the answer to provide you desired output.

```
COL1 <- c(1,1,1,NA,1,1)
COL2 <- c(1,NA,NA,1,1,1)
COL3 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
ind1 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
ind2 <- c(3,3,2,3,3,3)
Data <- data.frame (COL1, COL2, COL3, ind1, ind2)
actual <- c(5,3,4,1,1,2)
prediction <- c(1,1,2,5,5,1)

logic <- ifelse(actual > prediction, TRUE, FALSE)
```

The logic vector's output is:

```
> logic
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

data2<-Data
for (i in 1:NROW(Data)) {
  if (logic[i]) {
    data2[i,1:Data$ind2[i]] <- 1
  } else {
    data2[i,1:Data$ind1[i]] <- 0
  }
}
```

The loop output is as follows.

```
> data2
  COL1 COL2 COL3 ind1 ind2
1    1    1    1    1    3
2    1    1    1    2    3
3    1    1    1    1    2
4    0    0    0    2    3
5    0    0    0    1    3
6    1    1    1    2    3
```

It is not identical to you output because the logic output is true on the sixth location.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem the following way. However, I don't fully get your replacement logic. I left it out for this reason.

The following separates the condition and the replacement logic into a function. Hence you can easily use it for other data frames by simply calling it again with `apply`.

```
COL1 <- c(1,1,1,NA,1,1)
COL2 <- c(1,NA,NA,1,1,1)
COL3 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
ind1 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
ind2 <- c(3,3,2,3,3,3)

actual <- c(5,3,4,1,1,2)
prediction <- c(1,1,2,5,5,1)

Data <- data.frame (
  col1 = COL1, col2 = COL2, col3 = COL3, ind1 = ind1, ind2 = ind2,
  actual = actual, prediction = prediction)

custom.replace <- function(row) {
  # watch out! row is an atomic vector.
  if (row["actual"] > row["prediction"]) {
    # one of your replacement logic goes here.
  } else {
    # the other goes here.
  }
}

row.axis <- 1
apply(Data, row.axis, custom.replace)
```

I hope this helps!

PS: I know you want to use the `ìfelse` function. However, I don't see why you have to use it. Furhter, you can easily extend this solution such that it receives multiple inputs.